# JPA query does not work using sql function QUARTER

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Can you please help me with this problem?
objective is to extract all the tuples of a mySql table that fall within a precise quarter of each year, filtered on a Date type column
I used EntityManager and mapped Persistence Entity classes from database on maven project editor Eclipse.

come si deve comporre questa query in formato stringa/parametri per farla girare attraverso una Jpa Query? l'errore viene prodotto usando la parte finale con la funzione QUARTER

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) 
FROM mle.Draw d 
WHERE (d.deleted IS NULL OR d.deleted != 1) 
AND d.lotteryName = 'ITA_LOTTO'
AND d.wheel = 'BARI' 
AND QUARTER(d.drawDate) = 3;
```

if we insert the SQL query valued in edited mySDql directly on the DB it works correctly, while in the Java app we get this runtime error:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT d FROM Draw d WHERE (d.deleted IS NULL OR d.deleted !=1) AND (d.lotteryName = :lotteryName) AND (d.wheel = :wheel) AND (QUARTER(d.drawDate) = :px)].
[127, 154] The right expression is not a valid expression. and encryptedText={}. Error: {}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT d FROM Draw d WHERE (d.deleted IS NULL OR d.deleted !=1) AND (d.lotteryName = :lotteryName) AND (d.wheel = :wheel) AND (QUARTER(d.drawDate) = :px)].
[127, 154] The right expression is not a valid expression.
```

maybe JPA doesn't support some sql native function like QUARTER?! can you solve the problem?

Comment: If you want to use a native function you need to use a native query as well. JPA as you are using it above is supposed to be independent of the underlying database vendor, hence it is expected that MySQL specific function like quarter are not supported.

Comment: thanks OH GOD SPIDERS for the answer, yes i will use native query then!

Answer (score 0):

There simply is no `QUARTER` function available in JPQL.
Why don't you use native query to get your result?

Comment: thanks Asgar for the answer, Understood